# Does webpack packages files referenced in .angular-cli.json?

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster

There is a "styles" section and "scripts" section in `.angular-cli.json`.

I have added some files under "styles" and "scripts" sections. It appears that my angular project does not recognise these files.

Is webpack aware of the configurations inside .angular-cli.json?

Does webpack packages files referenced under "styles" and "scripts" section of `.angular-cli.json`? If yes, how can I be sure it is actually doing this? How can I trace which files are packed, which files aren't packed by webpack?

Following is the error I receive from webpack:

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/header/header.component.html
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg' in '/Users/halil/Projects/kodfarki/chargeback2/business-services/src/main/webapp/app/header'
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/header/header.component.html 1:4961-5000 1:5174-5213
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/header/header.component.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
```

Following is my folder structure:
[image]

Following is my .angular-cli.json definition:

```
"apps": [{
    "root": "src/main/webapp/",
    "outDir": "target/www/app",
    "assets": [
        "content",
        "dist",
        "favicon.ico"
    ],
```

Comment: Yes, it does ...

Comment: I updated my question @Faisal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using `jhipster` which is just partly supports angular cli([only for codegeneration purposes](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6050#issuecomment-314482508)). That is why your `scripts`, `assets` in your `.angular-cli.json` not making any effect as `jhipster` is using its own build chain. So with `jhipser` you have to do it a bit differently.

You need to use `vendor.ts` where you can reference your custom `css` and `js` files.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Then, the question is if I shouldn't define my resources inside `.angular-cli.json`, where should I define them? My resources are already under `src/main/webapp/app`. And I am able to access images if I use relative paths, such as, `../../dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg`. Should I inform webpack about my javascript, css resources?

Comment: import them in `vendor.ts`

Comment: Which files can I add into `vendor.ts`. Can I also add css files to `vendor.ts`?

Comment: reference both in there.